# Adding to the *end* of the gnu ld library search paths

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, gnu, ld, binutils

I know how to add to GNU ld's library search path using the -Ldir option and use it extensively. But as far as I can tell from reading the manuals of [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.4/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options) and [ld](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_mono/ld.html#IDX47), there is no way to add to the **end** of the list of library search paths.

The -L option adds to the beginning, after which it searches the default system library paths. But I want to add a look-here-if-you-can't-find-it-anywhwere-else path. Is there any way to do that with ld?

I can imagine a hacky-crap solution that extracts all standard library dirs (using -print-search-dirs) and adds them to the list of -L search dirs in the order I desire, ahead of their implied duplicates as default search paths...

But there *must* be a better way...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do exactly what you want.  However, what if you force all of the symbols in the libraries you're including to be weak with the following `ld` flag:

```
 -weak_library path_to_library
             This is the same as listing a file name path to a library on
             the link line except that it forces the library and all ref-
             erences to it to be marked as weak imports.
```

This way, if other libraries are included with stronger symbols, they'll override the symbols in `look-here-if-you-can't-find-it-anywhwere-else.so`.  If there are no stronger symbols defined in the libraries mentioned in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, the weak symbols in `look-here-if-you-can't-find-it-anywhwere-else.so` will be used.

Comment: Now if only I could remember the particular context that triggered this question...

Answer (score 0):

The **/etc/ld.so.conf** file has a system-wide list of directory paths where libraries are searched at compile-time, the newline separated order of entries of such file is honored.

After modifying that file you must run **ldconfig** (as root) so that the new setting becomes active.

Comment: This sounds **very** linux-specific. It may work for particular contexts, though.